# Filter output based on the existence of multiple key/value pairs

Tags: jmespath

Using JMESPath, is it possible to filter output based on the existence of multiple key/value pairs within the input?

From the example JSON below, what I'd like to do is extract only the objects that contain these key/value pairs within `Tags` -

> Environment / ABC
>   Project / Project2

The closest I can get is to select a single matching Tag, but I require the rest of the object too, and I also need to match against the other key/value pair -

```
Stacks[*].Tags[?Key=='Environment' && Value=='ABC']
```

Here is some exaple JSON input -

```
{
    "Stacks":  [
        {
            "StackId": "abc123",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "Project 1",
                    "Key": "Project"
                },
                {
                    "Value": "ABC",
                    "Key": "Environment"
                }
            ],
            "CreationTime": "2016-07-20T14:49:27.891Z",
            "StackName": "TestStack1",
            "NotificationARNs": [],
            "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
            "DisableRollback": false
        },
        {
            "StackId": "xyz123",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "Project 1",
                    "Key": "Project"
                },
                {
                    "Value": "XYZ",
                    "Key": "Environment"
                }
            ],
            "CreationTime": "2016-07-20T14:49:27.891Z",
            "StackName": "TestStack2",
            "NotificationARNs": [],
            "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
            "DisableRollback": false
        },
        {
            "StackId": "asd123",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "Project 2",
                    "Key": "Project"
                },
                {
                    "Value": "ABC",
                    "Key": "Environment"
                }
            ],
            "CreationTime": "2016-07-20T14:49:27.891Z",
            "StackName": "TestStack3",
            "NotificationARNs": [],
            "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
            "DisableRollback": false
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is the output that I require -

```
{
    "StackId": "asd123",
    "Tags": [
        {
            "Value": "Project 2",
            "Key": "Project"
        },
        {
            "Value": "ABC",
            "Key": "Environment"
        }
    ],
    "CreationTime": "2016-07-20T14:49:27.891Z",
    "StackName": "TestStack3",
    "NotificationARNs": [],
    "StackStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
    "DisableRollback": false
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use nested filters:

`Stacks[? Tags[? Value=='ABC' && Key=='Environment']]`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  For completeness, I used `Stacks[? Tags[? Value=='ABC' && Key=='Environment'] && Tags[? Value=='Project' && Key=='Project2']]` and it's working like a charm.

Comment: The person who designed this abomination probably looks down on COBOL because it's too wordy.