# aws-cli - Filtering output with --query and --filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Consider I want to query aws cli for an instance list that have the tag:

role=myrole

I want only the InstanceId and that specific tag, so i issue :

```
~ aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filter "Name=tag:role,Values=myrole" \
    --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,Tags[?Key=='myId'].Value]"
```

the reply will be :

```
[
    [
        [
            "i-111111111111111111",
            []
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "i-222222222222222222",
            [
                "091117"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "i-333333333333333333",
            []
        ]
    ]
]
```

How can i modify the query to get only objects that this tag Value is a non-empty strings ie :

```
[
    [
        [
            "i-222222222222222222",
            [
                "091117"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: If you query for a specific tag name and value, don't you already know the tag value? In that case the result shouldn't contain any empty tag values for the specific tag name at all.

Comment: Am I reading it read that you filter the query by a tag A and want the value of a tag B in the output?

Answer (score 9):

The only piece missing in your command is to ensure that the tag `myId` is present and has a non-empty value. That filter has to be applied to the selected instances (`Instances[*]`). How to filter for that is covered in [another answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41566023/4779904) and integrating it into your command is rather straight forward:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --filter "Name=tag:role,Values=myrole" \
  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[?Tags[?Key=='myId' && Value!='']].[InstanceId,Tags[?Key=='myId'].Value]"
```